# KeyError: 'accuracy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, plot, label

I was trying to plot train and test learning curve in keras, however, the following code produces KeyError: 'accuracy'
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
 #plotting graphs for accuracy 
plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='training accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='val accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='training loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='val loss')
plt.title('Loss')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

this is the error :

```
----> 3 plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'] , label='training accuracy')
KeyError: 'accuracy'
```

Comment: The error could likely be reproduced with the single line `history.history['accuracy']` meaning that what ever is in that variable doesn't have an "accuracy" item. So, the question is where that date comes from? If "accuracy" is supposed to be there, its a problem filling that structure in the first place. And since we don't know what that is, there isn't much we can do.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `metrics=['accuracy']` in model.fit() as

```
model.fit(#all other parameters, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

If you have already done so, check if you have written metrics=['acc'] instead. If so, make changes to this line in your code

```
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='training accuracy')
```

as

```
plt.plot(history.history['acc'], label='training accuracy')
```